# Rsync files between local directories

Tags: rsync

I want to use rsync to transfer files from one directory to another (on local computer). There are thousands of files in this directory each with form "Run####_m98-c14.root" and "Run####_98-c16.root"...I only want to transfer the files of the form "Run###_m98-c16.root"...Is there a way to do this? Thank You.

Comment: So, if I understand, you problem is just to build to source files list, not the rsync command by itself?

Can you post the command you already tried?

Comment: `rsync /path/to/Run*_m98-c16.root /destination/path/.`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I try to reproduce your source files:

```
cd /tmp
touch Run{1..20}_m98-c14.root
touch Run{1..20}_m98-c16.root
```

If you want to get only the ones containing "c16", to build this list, do:

```
ls Run*-c16.root
```

So, for rsync, the trick is:

```
rsync -rv --include 'Run*_m98-c16.root' /tmp /var/destdir
```

Comment: Is this what you needed? if yes, please consider accepting the answer.